# What is the problem with my implementation of Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to write my `Promise.all()` function.
It should repeat the functionality of the native `Promise.all()` method.

If there are only promises in the array, the code works correctly, probably the problem appears if the array contains something other than a promise.

**Here is an example of execution:**

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(3);

const p2 = 1337;

const p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 10000, 'foo');
});

promiseAll([p1, p3, p3]).then(values => console.log(values)); // [3, 1337, "foo"]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
const promiseAll = promises => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (promises.length === 0) { resolve([]); }
  const results = [];

  let resolved = 0;

  promises.forEach(promise => {
    if (!(promise instanceof Promise)) {
      Promise.resolve(promise).then(data => results.push(data));
    }
    promise.then(result => {
      results.push(result);
      resolved += 1;
      if (resolved === promises.length) {
        resolve(results);
      }
    }, error => reject(error));
  });
});
```

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Could you detail any error messages you are getting?

Comment: (node:15256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: promise.then is not a function

Comment: You're falling through even if your `promise` isn't a `Promise`.  Maybe add  an `else`.

Comment: Apart from the above mentioned, after you added a `return` or an `else`, your order is not guaranteed to be the same as the incoming promises. You push whatever is ready whenever it is ready. Also, you don't do anything regarding errors/rejection at all currently.

Answer (score 4):

Two main problems with your implementation:

1. Inside the `forEach()` method, you have a check: `promise instanceof Promise`. If this check is false, you call `Promise.resolve()` BUT then you also call `promise.then(...)`; you probably meant to call `then()` method inside an `else` block
2. `Promise.all()` maintains order - your implementation doesn't. This is because you just push the promise result in to the `results` array in the order in which the promises are resolved

You can change your implementation as shown below to fix the above mentioned problems:

```
const promiseAll = promises => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (promises.length === 0) {
          resolve([]);
          return;
        }

        const results = [];
        let resolved = 0;

        function collectResult(result, index) {
          results[index] = result;
          resolved += 1;
          if (resolved === promises.length) {
            resolve(results);
          }
        }

        promises.forEach((value, index) => {
          if (
            typeof value === 'object' &&
            'then' in value &&
            typeof value.then === 'function'
          ) {
            value.then(res => collectResult(res, index)).catch(reject);
          } else {
            Promise.resolve(value).then(res => collectResult(res, index));
          }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: The `else` part can be simplified to this: `collectResult(res, index)`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: following @Ivan Kleshnin comment here is the **parallel solution according to the spec**:

```js
Promise.all = async function (array) {
    const results = [];

     parllalLoopFinish = () =>{
        return results.length === array.length;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
            const promise = array[index];
            if(promise instanceof Promise){
                promise.then((value)=>{
                    results[index]=value;
                    if(parllalLoopFinish()) {
                        resolve(results);
                      }
                }).catch(reject)
            }
            else{
                results[index]=promise;
            }
        }
        if(parllalLoopFinish()) {
            resolve(results);
          }
    });

  };
  
  
  const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
  const promise2 = 42;
  const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
  });
  
  Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Because you are trying to invoke `then()` on p2 which is a number.

Here is how I implement `Promise.all()`

EDIT: old iterative solution

```js
Promise.all = async function (array) {
  const results = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
      try {
        const value = await Promise.resolve(array[index]);
        results.push(value);
      } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
  }
  return Promise.resolve(results);
};


const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((res) => console.log(res)); 
// print [3, 42, 'foo']
```

Comment: Your implementation runs promises sequentially which goes against the spec.

Comment: @IvanKleshnin thanks, I update my answer with the parallel solution

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new promise with Promise.resolve(promise) but you don't change the original promise var. Do

```
if (!(promise instanceof Promise)) {
  promise = Promise.resolve(promise);
}
```

Comment: I did it but I get this answer: [ 3, 1337, 2, 'foo' ]
I don't understand where 2

Comment: No idea, which input did you give it?

Comment: I indicated this in the problem

Comment: It was pushing to the array both in the if and out of it. Fixed the code. However notice you promiseAll doesn't keep the order of the promises! This is not what the spec says.